# What steps are required to swap an existing app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

That question makes no sense... so let me try to explain.

I have two apps already on the App Store. Let's call them Pro and Free. In short, I would like to copy Pro, change the copy slightly (removing a few features), and update Free by uploading the copy in its place.

(If anyone's curious, I want to handle it this way because I made a LOT of changes to Pro, all of which I need to make to Free as well. But it will be faster to copy Pro, strip out the Pro features, and rename this copy as Free.)

My question: Besides changing the Bundle Identifier of the copy to match Free's ID, are there any other changes that will be required to make this work?

Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the bundle identifier and the product name of your target.
For the future, if you have a free and pro version of the same app, and they share a big portion of code, you should consider just using one project, and create two targets instead. This way you can decide in the project which resources to bind to target Pro and target Free, and that's pretty much it. On deploy you just have to select the right target. Check [this link](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/)

Comment: Thank you! I will consider your suggestion.